# Html <option> background-color linear gradient

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

is there any option to make the backgrount of every `<option>` tag from a `<select>` tag contain different gradient colors?

As far as I could found there is a CSS option: `linear-gradient(direction,color1,color2)` which allows to set a gradient, but this option cannot be applied to the `background-color` attribute of each of the options.

if there is a solution I would like it to be many browser compatible, so it works in chrome, mozilla, Explorer, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is not applied to the `background-color`. It is the `background-image`.

So something like this should work for the browsers that support it (*combined with the `:nth-child` to target the specific option you want*).

```css
option:nth-child(1) {background: linear-gradient(to right, red, green);}
option:nth-child(2) {background: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue);}
option:nth-child(3) {background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow);}
option:nth-child(4) {background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red);}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>
```

---

*I believe thought, that only Firefox allows `background-image` setting on `option` elements.*

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to do in css.since its native elements which acts differently across different OS. But there is lot of plugins available online. Referring one which i used https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/